# Twin Prime Powers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

What are all the possible triplets of numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ such that $a+2=b$, $a+4=c$, and all $3$ are prime powers (where one must be a power of $3$)?

I'm aware of the cases for when they are below $15$ and the sequence of numbers in the range $23$ to $31$, as well as the triplets $(79, 81, 83)$ and $(239, 241, 243)$, but I'm under the inclination that no others exist. This is part of a stronger question in which I'm attempting to determine the quadruplets satisfying a similar condition, but it was simple to deduce at least one of the elements is a power of $3$, and for these quadruplets must be one of the middle two elements (except for the smallest sequences which I've already noted above).

This itself is part of a larger question where I'm attempting to determine the increasing behavior of the function 
$$f(n)=\text{lcm}[1, 2, \ldots, n]-\Lambda(n) $$
(where $\Lambda(n)$ denotes the Von Mangoldt function), which just so happens to be increasing around these prime powers; the maximum length of increase happens when sequences of prime powers with difference no more than $2$ occurs; the longest sequences are in the two sequences I've noted above, and shorter increases elsewhere.

Comment: $59049=3^{10}$, and 59051 and 59053 are prime.

Comment: By the way the sequence, 3,5,7,9,23,25,27,79,239,59049,... is not in the OEIS.  Someone ought to add it.

Comment: The next two terms: 450283905890997359$=3^{37}-4$,$36472996377170786399=3^{41}-4$.

Comment: I will note for the archive: the reason one number must be a power of $3$ is that all primes, and prime powers, $\gt 3$ are $\pm 1 \pmod 6$, therefore to extend a progression to three terms, one must be $3 \pmod 6$ which, being divisible by three and a prime power, can only be a power of three.

Comment: To the original question, since powers of three are so rare it is probably quickest to simply enumerate and test them, as I presume @MatthewConroy has done already up to $3^{41}$.

Comment: I've checked through $3^{154}$.

Comment: Is there any sequence of exactly $4$ consecutive prime powers among odd numbers?